# SWIG Or Boost -for Mapping C structures to Python

Tags: python, c, boost, swig, boost-python

I have requirement to map C Structures to Python. Any suggestion what will be the best approach to go for SWIG or Boost with least complexity.

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken, isn't Boost written in/for C++?

Comment: You confuse the two different languages C and C++!

Answer (score 0):

If your structures are in pure C, then it's very easy with both methods. Or, you may consider `ctypes`, though my favorite is SWIG -- it automates things a lot.

Comment: Thanks, What you think about maintaining the code base if we go for SWIG as compared to Boost Python?